# How to remove non-alphanumeric characters at the beginning or end of a string

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, character

I have a list with elements that have unnecessary (non-alphanumeric) characters at the beginning or end of each string.

Ex.

```
'cats--'
```

I want to get rid of the --

I tried:

```
for i in thelist:
    newlist.append(i.strip('\W'))
```

That didn't work. Any suggestions.

Comment: What characters would you consider innecessary?

Answer (score 11):

```
def strip_nonalnum(word):
    if not word:
        return word  # nothing to strip
    for start, c in enumerate(word):
        if c.isalnum():
            break
    for end, c in enumerate(word[::-1]):
        if c.isalnum():
            break
    return word[start:len(word) - end]

print([strip_nonalnum(s) for s in thelist])
```

Or

```
import re

def strip_nonalnum_re(word):
    return re.sub(r"^\W+|\W+$", "", word)
```

Comment: Can you explain why OR (|) is used? EDIT: nvm, it reflects the start or end of the string.

Answer (score 7):

To remove one or more chars other than letters, digits and `_` from both ends you may use

```
re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', '??cats--') # => cats
```

Or, if `_` is to be removed, too, wrap `\W` into a character class and add `_` there:

```
re.sub(r'^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$', '', '_??cats--_')
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gp7sKf/1) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5CW%2B%7C%5CW%2B%24):

[image]

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/kECclH):

```
import re
print( re.sub(r'^\W+|\W+$', '', '??cats--') )          # => cats
print( re.sub(r'^[\W_]+|[\W_]+$', '', '_??cats--_') )  # => cats
```

Comment: The regex graph is great ! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex expression. The method [`re.sub()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) will take three parameters:

- The regex expression
- The replacement
- The string

**Code:**

```
import re

s = 'cats--'
output = re.sub("[^\\w]", "", s)

print output
```

**Explanation:**

- The part `"\\w"` matches any alphanumeric character.
- `[^x]` will match any character that is *not* `x`

Comment: can you explain the "[^\\w]" part

Comment: i dont think that would work because i cant get rid of the unnecessary characters in the middle of the string, only in the beginning or the end.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this is the shortest non-regex solution:

```
text = "`23`12foo--=+"

while len(text) > 0 and not text[0].isalnum():
    text = text[1:]
while len(text) > 0 and not text[-1].isalnum():
    text = text[:-1]

print text
```

Answer (score 0):

By using strip you have to know the substring to be stripped.

```
>>> 'cats--'.strip('-')
'cats'
```

You could use `re` to get rid of the non-alphanumeric characters but you would shoot with a cannon on a mouse IMO. With `str.isalpha()` you can test any strings to contain alphabetic characters, so you only need to keep those:

```
>>> ''.join(char for char in '#!cats-%' if char.isalpha())
'cats'
>>> thelist = ['cats5--', '#!cats-%', '--the#!cats-%', '--5cats-%', '--5!cats-%']
>>> [''.join(c for c in e if c.isalpha()) for e in thelist]
['cats', 'cats', 'thecats', 'cats', 'cats']
```

You want to get rid of non-alphanumeric so we can make this better:

```
>>> [''.join(c for c in e if c.isalnum()) for e in thelist]
['cats5', 'cats', 'thecats', '5cats', '5cats']
```

This one is exactly the same result you would get with re (as of [Christian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22650549/2334951)):

```
>>> import re
>>> [re.sub("[^\\w]", "", e) for e in thelist]
['cats5', 'cats', 'thecats', '5cats', '5cats']
```

However, If you want to strip non-alphanumeric characters from the end of the strings only you should use another pattern like this one (check [re Documentation](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html)):

```
>>> [''.join(re.search('^\W*(.+)(?!\W*$)(.)', e).groups()) for e in thelist]
['cats5', 'cats', 'the#!cats', '5cats', '5!cats']
```

Comment: All code examples except the last fail to remove only leading/trailing non-alphanumeric characters. You could [simplify the regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22659601/4279)

Comment: I was aware of that, however I missed `str.isalnum()` there. Thanks for sharing your regex and answer.