# How to remove numbers and alphanumeric at the begining of sentence untill word occurrs in python dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a data frame which consists of numbers, words, and alphanumeric. I need to remove numbers and alphanumeric until word occurs.
Here is the data frame

```
       text
0     5dgt468h at 56 home every day 6 to 8
1     I am going home at 6
2     6 pm is the evening
3     45 67 are numbers 
4     33 23 45ghd4  are junk
```

what I need is

```
       text
0     at 56 home every day 6 to 8
1     I am going home at 6
2     pm is the evening
3     are numbers 
4     are junk
```

Comment: `^\W+` or `^[\W_]+` will be enough, see explanations in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57665025/3832970).

Comment: No it's not working

Comment: Sorry, looks like I was too sleepy. You need `df['text'].str.replace(r'^\s*(?:(?:\d+[^\W\d_]|[^\W\d_]+\d)[^\W_]*|\d+)(?:\s+(?:(?:\d+[^\W\d_]|[^\W\d_]+\d)[^\W_]*|\d+))*\s*', '')`, see [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XiHIZq/1).